# Open new tabs with portal react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, window.open, createelement, react-portal

Im trying to open a new tab with portal, the problem is that the tab not display the content that i want to get a prev, i follow this [post](https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202) and the tab open perfectly, but not display the content and look like this:
[image]

This is my react portal code:

```
    import ReactDOM, {PureComponent} from 'react';

export default class Portal extends PureComponent{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.containerEl = null;
    this.externalWindow = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400,left=200,top=200');
    this.containerEl = this.externalWindow.document.createElement('div');
    this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    this.externalWindow.close();
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.containerEl) {
      return null;
    } 
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children,this.containerEl);  
  }
}
```

And this is my code where im opening the new tab:

```
{this.state.showWindowPortal && (
            <Portal closeWindowPortal={this.closeWindowPortal} >
            <p>Hello</p>
       <button onClick={() => this.closeWindowPortal()} >Close me! 
  </button>
</Portal>)}
```

I hope you guys can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're not creating `containerEl` soon enough. (It doesn't need to be created in the other window's document, which I assume is why you were delaying it.) To fix it, change `this.containerEl = null;` to `this.containerEl = document.createElement('div');` in the constructor, and remove `this.containerEl = this.externalWindow.document.createElement('div');` from `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` gets executed after `render`.

`this.containerEl`  is getting set to `this.externalWindow.document.createElement('div');` in `componentDidMount`.

You are checking `this.containerEl` in `render` and at that time `this.containerEl` is `null`.

For more information on the order of React's lifecycle hooks please check http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/